# iPhone YouTube music player (background and no video)

Tags: youtube, music.app

On Android there is an app called PVStar+ which is a YouTube player that lets the user play music in the background and turn off video. Is there such an application for the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty but you should give a try to Foxtube (FoxTube 4 - Player for YouTube par mix1009
https://appsto.re/ca/CgFO2.i) and Protube (ProTube for YouTube par Jonas Gessner
https://appsto.re/ca/GkqG3.i)

Answer (score 0):

[Tubex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tubex-videos-music-for-youtube/id939906112?mt=8) is the best one I've found.  You can put Tubex in the background or even turn off the screen and YouTube music keeps playing.  You can also login to your YouTube account and access favorites, playlists, etc...

I've had it on my phone for months now in a variety of situations and with different people controlling the music and it's very stable and reliable.